# Nuxt 3 scrollBehaviour not waiting for page to finish loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

My project is built with Nuxt3. Currently I have a link from page A to an anchor within a component on page B. The expected behaviour is that user clicks this link and is then scrolled to that the component page B.

However, on page B there are several components that wait for api requests to resolve before being loaded in, which I believe is impacting where the page scrolls to.

Looking in the docs I've found

```
hooks.hook('page:finish', async () => {})
```

Which I believe is supposed to wait for the page (and all child components on that page) to finish loading. However, if I put a console log in the onMounted() in each of the components I can see there is a timing issue where my page:finish hook is not the last thing to get. But instead, the other logs in the child components are called afterwards. Suggesting this hook isn't actually waiting for the page to complete loading.

I know I can extend the timeout in global scrollBehaviour() but i'd rather not as thats used across my project for other uses which don't require a long delay.

Does anyone know a way to check the parent page is fully loaded, before triggering the scroll event?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the page:finish hook is not suitable for your use case, since it might not wait until all the data requests have completed. One alternative option you can try is to use watch() with a global state to keep track of the loading state of your components. Once all the components have finished loading, you can trigger the scroll event accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`page:finish` is triggered when the page has been rendered. It does not wait for any API call the page might have made, which would then trigger further updates to the page layout.

What should work is calling

```
nextTick(() => router.go())
```

after the page updated the data.

To my knowledge, it reloads the page softly, navigating to any `#hash` the URL might contain.