Nuxt js 3 scroll behavior after page and data load completed
I'd like to delay the scroll behaviour until the page is mounted and the data is loaded properly. I've managed to delay the scroll behaviour until the page is mounted using the lifecycle hooks provided by Nuxt. However, before all the data is loaded, the page is scrolled immediately and not waiting for all the data to be loaded. So, when I go back using web browser's back button, the page lands randomly (mostly on the footer). Could anyone help me with this, please? What do I probably miss?
<script lang="ts" setup> 
new Promise(resolve => {
   nuxtApp.hooks.hookOnce('page:finish', () => {
      return resolve({
         top: 0,
         behavior: 'smooth'
      })
   })
})

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    await loadData()
})
</script>


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78167534/6415571 Check this out
